# How to interpret a probability involving two random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Prove that $P(a<X\le b, c<Y\le d) = F(b,d)-F(b,c)-F(a,d)+F(a,c)$.

For one random variable, you could intuitively see that $$P(a<X\le b) = F(b)-F(a)$$ from the corresponding probability density function graph (probability denotes the area between $x=a$ and $x=b$).

However, how would you interpret the above question: $$P(a<X\le b, c<Y\le d)=F(b,d)-F(b,c)-F(a,d)+F(a,c)$$ when the joint probability density function is hard to visualize (for example, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=xye^{-(x+y)}$ to name one case)? In other words, why is the expression $$P(a<X\le b, c<Y\le d)$$ always equals $$F(b,d)-F(b,c)-F(a,d)+F(a,c)$$

A little visual aid in your answer would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about visualizing the density but a simple thing about the regions (of integration). Please examine the figure below.

---

There should be no need for explanation, but just for the record:

The black lines with ticks are the $X$ and $Y$ axes, but it should be clear that they play no role (the location of the origin doesn't matter).

The desired $P(a<X\le b, c<Y\le d)$ is the probability mass contained in the purple rectangle, from the lower left corner of $(a,c)$ to upper right corner $(b,d)$.

$F(b,d)$ is the probability contained in the biggest rectangle, from the "lower left corner" at $(-\infty,\infty)$ to upper right corner $(b,d)$.

[image]

$F(b,c)$ is the probability contained in a less big rectangle, from the "lower left corner" of still $(-\infty, \infty)$ to upper right corner $(b,c)$. This is the region below the blue horizontal dotted line (the lower one, an extension of the lower edge of the purple rectangle).

$F(a,d)$ is the probability in another less-big rectangle, from the "lower left corner" of as always $(-\infty, \infty)$ to upper right corner $(a,d)$. This is the region left to the green dashed line (the left one, an extension of the left edge of the purple rectangle).

So at this point $F(b,d) - F(b,c) - F(a,d)$ gives you the desired purple rectangle but an extra $-F(a,c)$, which is the overlap region of $F(b,c)$ and $F(a,d)$.

Thus we add $F(a,d)$ back and $$P(\text{purple rectangle})=F(b,d)-F(b,c)-F(a,d)+F(a,c)$$

Comment: Amazing answer, Thanks!